# Distinct in LINQ to SQL is not working as expected(at all)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an ASPX webpage that contains a combobox and a listbox. When a user makes a selection the listbox is supposed to be populated with distinct years.

The datasource that fuels this is a .dbml that has one table and contains a Date column. Has data like this:

```
2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
2017-01-06 00:00:00.000
2017-01-06 00:00:00.000
2018-01-11 00:00:00.000
2018-01-11 00:00:00.000
2018-01-11 00:00:00.000
2017-10-03 00:00:00.000
2017-10-03 00:00:00.000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

So in the listbox I expect only:

```
2017
2018
```

but, instead, get every year.

```
2018
2017
2017
2018
2018
2018
2017
2017
2018
```

My LINQ looks like:

```
Using context As New ACE_Data Context()
    Dim aircraft As String = comboSelectAircraft.Value
    Dim year As Table(Of A_DETAIL_REPO) = context.A_DETAIL_REPOs
    Dim query = From ace In context.GetTable(Of A_DETAIL_REPO)()
                Where ace.Series.Equals(aircraft)
                Select DateAndTime.Year(ace.Date)
                Distinct 
    listYear.DataSource = query 
    listYear.DataBind()
End Using
```

I'm not sure where this is going on.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part `DateAndTime.Year(ace.Date)` can't be translated into SQL. In such cases, LINQ-to-SQL auto-switches to *client-side evaluation*. That is, it executes as much as possible in SQL and then continues in .Net code to do the part that can't be translated.

But here this approach fails, because the part that's executes as SQL is:

```
From ace In context.GetTable(Of A_DETAIL_REPO)()
Where ace.Series.Equals(aircraft)
Select ace.Date
Distinct
```

On the result list of *that* query `DateAndTime.Year(ace.Date)` is applied client-side. So, in short, you get the year parts of distinct dates, not the distinct year parts of dates.

The solution is to use `ace.Date.Year`. This can be translated into the SQL `DATEPART` function, so `DISTINCT` will be applied to the years.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that really helped. I didn't know LINQ-to-SQL could switch evaluation methods.  As a side note, I ended up having to use ace.Date.Value.Year as ace.Date.Year threw an exception.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Dim query = (From ace In context.GetTable(Of A_DETAIL_REPO)()
            Where ace.Series.Equals(aircraft)
            Select DateAndTime.Year(ace.Date)).Distinct()
```

This will force your select statment to return an IEnumerable and then you can use the .Distinct() method on the IEnumerable interface.